# Files not getting uploaded from react hook forms to backend server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, rxjs

Hey guys i am learning react and I am trying to upload image from react hook forms to a django server. I am having trouble with the form as text data is being passed on but the image is not getting send from the form. I am not sure, the code I have is correctly written. Can anyone please check the code and help solving the problem? I have checked the api endpoint with postman and it works fine.

form

```
export default function PostCreate() {
const classes = useStyles();

const [postimage, setPostImage] = useState(null);


const handleChange = (e) => {
    if ([e.target.name] === 'image') {
        setPostImage({
            postimage: e.target.files,
        });
        console.log(e.target.files);
    }
    
}


const { register, handleSubmit, control, errors } = useForm();

const onSubmit = (data) =>{
    let formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('title', data.title);
    formData.append('user', 1);
    formData.append('image', data.image);

    axiosInstance.post(`api/posts/create/`, formData);
    console.log(data)
} ;
console.log(errors);

return (
    <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
        <CssBaseline />
        <div className={classes.paper}>
            <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                Post!
            </Typography>

            <form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                <Grid container spacing={2}>
                    <Grid item xs={12}>
                        <TextField
                            variant="outlined"
                            fullWidth
                            id="title"
                            type="text" 
                            placeholder="Title"
                            autoComplete="title" 
                            name="title" 
                            inputRef={register({required: true, maxLength: 1000})}
                            multiline
                            rows={4}
                        />
                    </Grid>

                    <label htmlFor="post-image">
                        <input
                        accept="image/*"
                        className={classes.input}
                        id="post-image"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        name="image"
                        type="file"
                        inputRef={register}
                    />
                        Image
                        <IconButton color="primary" component="span">
                            <PhotoCamera />
                        </IconButton>
                    </label>

                </Grid>
                <Button
                    type="submit"
                    fullWidth
                    variant="contained"
                    color="primary"
                    className={classes.submit}
                    name="button"
                >
                    Create Post
                </Button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </Container>
);

}
```

`console.log(data)` is showing `{title: "kjhkdjfnd"}` and not the image field.
`console.log(data.image)` is showing undefined. What can be the reason?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `handleChange` handler, `[e.target.name] === 'image'` is equivalent to `['image'] === 'image'`, which will always be false and hence the image is not being set in state.

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
    if (e.target.name === "image") {
        setPostImage({
            postimage: e.target.files,
        });
        console.log(e.target.files);
    }
};
```

This should work.

Answer (score 2):

in react hooks form you wants use special component , you should use Controller component of react-hooks-form. you shouldent use diffrent state for keeping your files.

i think you should write your upload inpus like below :

```
import { Controller } from 'react-hook-form';

        <Controller
                control={control}
                render={({ onChange }) => (
                    <FormControl>
                    <Input type="file" onChange={e => onChange(e.target.files[0])} />
                    </FormControl>
                )}
                />;
```

Comment: I am getting this error now `
TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`